# Git Submodule Not Seen in GitBox

Tags: git, gitbox

I'm sure something is wrong with my git directory.

I set up my submodule using

```
git submodule add ssh://someUrl/confusionutil.git confusionUtil
```

and this all works well. Seems like the submodule is acting right and has a .git file that says:

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/confusionUtil
```

However: Gitbox doesn't recognize it as a submodule (nor as a git repo)... it does with another submodule I'm using, so...

Ideas? What could be wrong with my submodule?

Comment: Did you initialize and update that submodule? (`git submodule update --init`). Did you add and commit that new submodule entry in your local repo?

Comment: Thanks @VonC, the answer was in there. Basically `git submodule update` was erroring on another submodule that did not have a submodule mapping, so I guess it never finished.

Comment: Ok, I have described that error in a answer below for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Yar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8047/yar) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107976/git-submodule-not-seen-in-gitbox#comment33589724_22107976), the issue stemmed from the update process:

One of the submodule (without the proper `.gitmodule` mapping) was causing the update to fail, before the `confusionUtil` submodule could get updated itself.

Comment: Thanks man. git.stackoverflow.com should point to http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc ;)

Comment: @Yar fortunately, I am not the only Git specialist on Stack Overflow, far from it ;)